# AspNet Core RC2 Model binding gives null model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core-rc2

I am working with ASP.NET CORE RC2 and I have the following model binder:

```
public class MovieModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(MovieViewModel))
        {
            var idValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Id").FirstValue;
            var nameValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Name").FirstValue;

            var timespanProperty = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Properties.Single(p => p.PropertyName == "Length");
            var timespanValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(timespanProperty.PropertyName).FirstValue;

            int minutes;
            int.TryParse(timespanValue, out minutes);

            int id;
            int.TryParse(idValue, out id);

            var model = new MovieViewModel
            {
                Length = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes),
                Id = id,
                Name = nameValue
            };

            return Task.FromResult(ModelBindingResult.Success(bindingContext.ModelName, model));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(default(ModelBindingResult));
    }
}
```

I am using it on a controller action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MovieModelBinder))] MovieViewModel model)
{
    // Code here
}
```

Problem is that I get a null model every time. What is exactly wrong with the ModelBindingResult.Success method and what change should be made to return correct results?

Comment: I am not much experianced but I think there is some issue with your return, should't your return will be `MovieViewModel` type?

Comment: Can you provide an example on that please?

Comment: I have done a basic sample `ModelBinder` Example , I will post in Answers, maybe that will helpful for you

Comment: Not sure whats wrong, for me same code stopped working after rc2 update. For workaround just manually assign : bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(bindingContext.ModelName, model); before return Task.FromResult(...);

Comment: @user1214919 Thank you it works. Weird, though, I haven't found something related in documentation (in bits and parts I've looked so far), it only says to return the 'ModelBindingResult.Success(bindingContext.ModelName, model)'.
You can post this as an answer if you like, so other people can see it. I will accept it. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whats wrong, for me same code stopped working after rc2 update.

For workaround just manually assign :

```
bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(bindingContext.ModelName, model);
```

before

```
return Task.FromResult(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe not a Answer to your question but as an example I am posting it here

This `ModelBinder` example bind the posted values to my `UrlValidation` Type

```
 public class MBUser : IModelBinder
    {

        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            HttpContextBase httpContextBase = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;
            UrlValidation urlValidation = new UrlValidation();
            //Binding posted values to UrlValidation type
            urlValidation.Expirydate = DateTime.ParseExact(
                httpContextBase.Request["UrlValidation.Expirydate"].ToString(),
                "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("G");
            urlValidation.ProjectTypeID = Convert.ToInt16(httpContextBase.Request["ProjectType"]);
            urlValidation.Url = httpContextBase.Request["UrlValidation.Url"].ToString();
            string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
            urlValidation.CreateDate = datetime;
            // returning UrlValidation type
            return urlValidation; 
        }
    }
```

I am using it on a controller action like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Enter([ModelBinder(typeof(MBUser))] UrlValidation rulValidation)
        {
           // my methods
        }
```

Hope this will help somehow.

Comment: I see, but I am looking for an answer on ASP.NET Core RC2, not on ASP.NET MVC previous versions.

Comment: ohh..!! then my example is invalid here.